# Add more than two variable into one variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am getting all the a tag attributes using jquery function, now I want to store them into one and append in body, but cant find the way how to get it done. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuyfK/) link

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
var name= $(this).attr('name');
var href= $(this).attr('href');
var jj= $(this).attr('class');
var user_id= $(this).attr('user_id');
var page_type= $(this).attr('page_type');
var price= $(this).attr('price');
var bonus= $(this).attr('bonus');
var wrapper= $(this).attr('wrapper');
var token= $(this).attr('token');
var own= $(this).attr('own');
$('body').append('<div>'+name+'<div>')
})})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="profile_2902" name="b_now" href="#" class="big_now" user_id="152402569967" page_type="profile" price="292" bonus="0" wrapper="5972569967" token="e644ce48aa43dc3caa348745a" own="4100447132">
Click now!
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please show us a sample of what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use raw js to get all attributes and print them with jquery like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("someId");
var arr = [];
for (var i=0, attrs=el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    arr.push(attrs.item(i).nodeValue);
}
$('body').append('<div>'+arr.join(", ")+'<div>');
```

[Working fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cuyfK/5/)

Comment: What is item in your function and what is the use of it

Comment: It gets an item from the attrs array

Comment: is item is method of javascript ?  and why we cant use attrs[i]

Comment: The item() method returns the node at the specified index in a node list. see: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_nodelist_item.asp

Comment: can we use attrs[i] instead of item

Comment: Thanks for make me understand it

Comment: One more thing, i want make it happen only once when user click it. second time it should not work any idea how to do ti

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function below to read all attributes and push them in array..

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cuyfK/1/

```
    var el = this, arr = [], it;
    for (var i = 0, attrs = el.attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++) {

        it = attrs.item(i);

        if (it.nodeName == 'id') {
            arr.push(it.nodeName + '="' + it.nodeValue + '_fixed"');
        } else {
            arr.push(it.nodeName + '="' + it.nodeValue + '"');
        }
    }
```

or May be you want to push specific attr values inside an array.. Try below,

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var attr = [];
        attr.push($(this).attr('name'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('href'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('class'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('user_id'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('page_type'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('price'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('bonus'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('wrapper'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('token'));
        attr.push($(this).attr('own'));

        $('body').append('<div>' + attr.join(' ') + '<div>')   
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you use item in your function

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store the attributes you wish to look up, and then just iterate over that array with `$.each` to find all the values and concentenate them into a string and append them all in one go to be more efficient :

```
$(function(){
    var attributes = ['name', 'href', 'class', 'user_id', 'page_type',
                      'price', 'bonus', 'wrapper', 'token', 'own']

    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var html='', self=this;
        $.each(attributes, function(i,e) {
            html += '<br><div>'+e+' : '+$(self).attr(e);
        });
        $('body').append(html);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cuyfK/4/)